# How to disable Win key of on-screen keyboard?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

I have a app that use in a kiosk. I disable task-bar and win key in registry with `SetWindowsHookEx`.

But can open startmenu  when use On-Screan keyboard. I use `PreviewKeyDown` event, but don't work.

```
private void Window_PreviewKeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
 {
  if (e.Key == Key.LWin || e.Key==Key.RWin)
     e.Handled = true;
 }
```

How to disable win key of on-screan keyboard?

Comment: If you're running your application in kiosk mode...IMO what you have to do is to do not load Windows shell at all. Many things (and shortcuts) must be disabled. Just change shell from explorer.exe to your application executable, disable task manager (with gpedit) and et voila. Your application will be the shell. No start menu at all (it doesn't matter where it comes from) and no _dangerous_ shortcuts like Win+R or Win-E.

Comment: I have a app that run startup, and fill all desktop. kiosk work with on-screan keyborad. I want to disable startmenu that users can't open any program or drivers.

Comment: Kiosk mode is not just full-screen application without taskbar. You can disable start menu but onscreen keyboard will still send it (unless you change keymapping). Moreover users can run task manager. If you want a kiosk mode then **configure Windows to run in kiosk mode** (no task manager, no shell). That's the way to do it.

Comment: Think: type CTRL+ESC or Win to open start menu. Type CTRL-SHIFT-ESC to open TaskManager. Type ALT-F4 to close your application. Type Win+R to run an arbitrary program. Type Win+E to open Windows Explorer. Win+Down to restore and minimize. And this is just the beginning of this list. Do you want to manage them all? **Windows can be configured in kiosk mode** (and it's a question for SuperUser), your **application must not care** about that (as you don't care to support every printer out there...)

Comment: my kiosk is without keyboard. it only has the onscreen keyboard that it's not possible to open the task manager by it. the only problem is the opening of start menu by the onscreen keyboard win-K.

Comment: @Niloo, How did you do it. looking at the answer given below, how do i use the project?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This person seems to have it sorted http://sleepydesign.blogspot.co.uk/2013/07/c-disable-system-keys-on-windows-on.html

But the appear from their [github](https://github.com/katopz/oskz-vcsharp/tree/master/MouseKeyboardActivityMonitor) to be using the same approach to hooks

I imagine my scan of the code missed something, they're quite confident it works, explicitly refering to the onscreen keyboard and disabling specific functionality
.

I believe he virtual code for windows key is

```
MOD_WIN      (0x0008)
```

Also take a look at [RegisterHotKey](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms646309%28VS.85%29.aspx)

Comment: How do i use this in visual studio? I have application that requires only to use the onscreen keyboard, but with some keys disabled e.g the win key, Ctrl, shift, Alt, all functional keys etc